# WinApi SetTimer cannot compile

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, casting

I need timer to start function every 1 second.

I have tried `SetTimer`, my code:

```
const UINT_PTR TIMER_ID = 1000;

DWORD DownloadThread()
{
    SetTimer(NULL, TIMER_ID, 1000, (TIMERPROC)DownloadSpeedCounter);
    /*some stuff*/
}

void DownloadSpeedCounter()
{
    /*some stuff*/
}
```

I cannot compile this code and get `error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'TIMERPROC'`

Also it is class member method.

Comment: The compiler is telling you what the problem is. `SetTimer()` expects a function with a specific signature, and yours doesn't match.

Comment: Using SetTimer() in a thread that doesn't pump a message loop doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to use a normal function as an application-defined callback function. What you are probably looking for is this application-defined callback function which could look like this:

```
VOID CALLBACK DownloadSpeedCounter( 
HWND hwnd,        // handle to window for timer messages 
UINT message,     // WM_TIMER message 
UINT idTimer,     // timer identifier 
DWORD dwTime) {
     /* some stuff */
}
```

For additional information on using callback functions for timers see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The problem remained anyway.

Comment: I have read that article before, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18312253/1237747) it explains everything, also your answer helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that `TIMERPROC` functions should look like this: `typedef VOID (CALLBACK* TIMERPROC)(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD);` So your method definition should look like this:

```
VOID CALLBACK DownloadSpeedCounter(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD);
```

Also, as this is a method, not just a function, it must be `static`. So it is calling like `static` but to access private non-static data may be used [this technique.](http://www.greengingerwine.com/index.php/2011/05/using-the-windows-settimer-api-with-cpp-objects/)